# getSymbols downloading multiple currency pairs from oanda in a single data frame

Tags: r

I am currently downloading currency pairs from Oanda using `getSymbols` and here is my code:

```
Currency.Pairs <- as_tibble(c("EUR/USD", "USD/JPY", "GBP/USD", "EUR/GBP"))

colnames(Currency.Pairs) <- "Pairs"

getSymbols(Currency.Pairs$Pairs, src = "oanda", from = "2012-01-01", to = "2016-12-20")
```

output:

```
[1] "EURUSD" "USDJPY" "GBPUSD" "EURGBP"
```

Is there a way that I can download all the prices of currency prices in one single list or data frame, instead of dataframes for each currency pair? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Oh you poor dears

Comment: It is not useful to have all security data into one list or data.frame. I would suggest creating a new environment, sourcing individual series and merging them as final step. `newEnv = new.env();getSymbols(Symbols=Currency.Pairs$Pairs,env=newEnv,...) ; allTimeSeries = do.call(merge.xts,as.list(newEnv))`

Answer (score 0):

The `env` (environment) parameter of `getSymbols` allows creation of a secure location to store
and manipulate the price data as below:

```
#tibble library is not required (tibble::as_tibble)

Currency.Pairs <- c("EUR/USD", "USD/JPY", "GBP/USD", "EUR/GBP")

#create new environment to house all price data
newEnv = new.env()

#source data
getSymbols(Currency.Pairs, src = "oanda",env=newEnv, from = "2012-01-01", to = "2016-12-20")

#merge all price series
allTimeSeries = do.call(merge.xts,as.list(newEnv))

#convert column names to original form EUR.USD => EUR/USD
colnames(allTimeSeries) = gsub("[.]","\\/",colnames(allTimeSeries))

#reorder columns as per original order
allTimeSeries = allTimeSeries[,Currency.Pairs]

head(allTimeSeries)
#           EUR/USD USD/JPY GBP/USD  EUR/GBP
#2012-01-01 1.29590 76.8892 1.55384 0.833490
#2012-01-02 1.29375 76.9584 1.55049 0.834425
#2012-01-03 1.30038 76.7861 1.55779 0.834755
#2012-01-04 1.30036 76.6969 1.56310 0.831920
#2012-01-05 1.28717 76.8753 1.55586 0.827300
#2012-01-06 1.27698 77.1381 1.54737 0.825255

tail(allTimeSeries)
#          EUR/USD USD/JPY GBP/USD  EUR/GBP
#2016-12-15 1.04682 117.772 1.25015 0.837350
#2016-12-16 1.04349 118.106 1.24366 0.839055
#2016-12-17 1.04510 117.915 1.24884 0.836935
#2016-12-18 1.04512 117.913 1.24887 0.836930
#2016-12-19 1.04458 117.339 1.24500 0.839030
#2016-12-20 1.03906 117.695 1.23718 0.839870
```